# Passing two variables from php to ajax using dropdown

Tags: php, ajax, onchange

How can I pass the two values (filter & $user_id) to Ajax?

**PHP:**

```
$user_id = 3; 
echo "<select name=\"filter\" data-userid=\"".$user_id."\"
onchange=\"getPoints(this.value)\">
<option value=\"one\">One</option>
<option value=\"two\">Two</option>
</select>";
```

**AJAX**:

```
function getPoints(filter)
{
    var userid = $(this).attr('data-userid');

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: 'http://website.com?user_id='+userid,
data: '&action='+filter,
success: function(result){
$("#Target").html(result);
}
});
};
```

I want to get this url:

```
http://website.com?user_id=3&action=one
```

I have the problem with passing $user_id to Ajax.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: give an id to select control and try to append <option>value<option> dynamically by jaquery,ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code should be like

```
function getPoints(filter)
{
    var userid = $(this).attr('data-userid');

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://website.com',
        data: {action: filter, user_id: user_id},
        success: function (result) {
            $("#Target").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Or if I talk about your way then it should be

```
function getPoints(filter)
{
    var userid = $(this).attr('data-userid');

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://website.com?user_id='+userid+'&action='+filter,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#Target").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

It is always better to use `data: {action: filter, user_id: user_id}` because it will treated like object itself.

**EDIT**
JS

```
 function getPoints(filter)
    {
        var user_id = document.getElementById('test_class').getAttribute('data-userid');
        console.log(user_id);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://website.com',
            data: {action: filter, user_id: user_id},
            success: function (result) {
                $("#Target").html(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

PHP

```
$user_id = 3; 
echo "<select id='test_class' name=\"filter\" data-userid=\"".$user_id."\"
onchange=\"getPoints(this.value)\">
<option value=\"one\">One</option>
<option value=\"two\">Two</option>
</select>";
```

Comment: The problem with (var userid = $(this).attr('data-userid');) He returns **undefined**

Comment: I need to use **function getPoints(filter)**. The name of the function is important for my project. Your first solution did not work. The problem is with returning the **userid**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
function getPoints(filter){
  var userid = $(this).data('userid');

  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'http://website.com?user_id='+userid,
  data: { action:filter, user_id: userid},
  success: function(result){
   $("#Target").html(result);
  }
 });
};
```

Comment: The problem with (var userid = $(this).attr('data-userid');) He returns **undefined**.

Comment: I use alert('userid: ' + userid); and het returns userid: **undefined**.

Comment: @NachoMoço : Thanks for your support